# Regular crashes of WindowServer

Tags: macos, imac, crash

My Mac crashes regularly because of WindowServer problems. The problem persists for about 5 years. Sometimes its a crash every few days, then there are periods with a crash every few hours. I did not find a pattern right now.

The Mac is a iMac Retina 5K, 27", end of 2015. MacOS is 12.2.1.

Updating and reinstalling did not change anything. The Mac got a new motherboard three years ago, but the problem seems not related to this.

Running Apple Diagnostic does not show any defects.

[Linked please find a crash report](https://sprechkultur.com/cr.txt)

[Linkes please find the results of kextstat](https://sprechkultur.com/kx.txt)

Edit:
It's so normal to me, I forgot to mention: The mac has a second display, crashes only occur with the second display connected, but regardless of connection method:

It's a DELL U2715H running at native resolution of 2560 × 1440 connected via Display Port -> HDMI cable.

Edit:
Added [another Crash Report](https://sprechkultur.com/cr2.txt) and [another Crash Report](https://sprechkultur.com/cr3.txt) and [yet another](https://sprechkultur.com/cr4.txt) as suggested.

Answer (score 2):

Relevant bits of crash report:

```
[...]

Exception Type:        EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Codes:       KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x00007ff7b0ead112

[...]

VM Region Info: 0x7ff7b0ead112 is not in any region.  Bytes after previous region: 274742300947  Bytes before following region: 168296174

[...]

Thread 0 Crashed::  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
0   QuartzCore                          0x7ff821521918 CA::Render::Update::added_all_contexts() + 714
1   SkyLight                            0x7ff81f4c5d4b WSCALayerBacking::RunUpdate(WSCARenderContextScope&, bool) + 527

[...]
```

What this means to an OS developer is that `WindowServer` (which is the process on every Mac that does the job of drawing everything on your screen) is attempting to access data at a virtual address that is not mapped to any valid process or resource. This is *always* the result of **a bug somewhere along the software, firmware, or hardware stack**.

The fact that it has been occurring for so long (well, I am *presuming* this, based on your original report; it would be helpful if we could compare the crash reports from previous versions of macOS, but I doubt that you still have these) and therefore has persisted across major macOS releases suggests that there is something unusual about your specific system. This nudges us towards either a **hardware bug** or an **unhandled corner case in firmware or software** for certain hardware abnormalities.

Here are some things to try, in approximate order:

- Append your original problem posting with a code block containing the result of the following Terminal command: `kextstat`
- Collect and post more crash reports so that we can compare what changes and what stays the same between crashes
- Run [Apple Diagnostics](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202731) to check for obvious hardware issues
- Try running with lower screen resolutions
- Boot into Safe Mode (hold <kbd>Shift</kbd>) during boot. This will almost certainly eliminate the problem because you'll be running with unaccelerated graphics, which will cause the rendering software to follow a very different code path, but will almost certainly be unusable for real productivity. This is an important data point to collect, however.
- Bring your Mac to an Apple Authorized Service Center to see if they can swap other components (e.g., the display flex cable).

Comment: I've added the results of kextstat as suggested

Comment: @DrSvanHay Ok, that rules out third-party KEXTs that may be stomping on protected memory. Thanks!

Comment: Apple Diagnostics yields no results. I'm going to collect further reports when crashes happen.

Comment: More reports added. Save mode seems to disable crashes as far as I can tell.

Comment: @DrSvanHay Have you tried creating a new user and then rebooting and using that user?

Comment: @DrSvanHay Thanks for the additional crash reports. They are helpful. Your info about the 2nd display is very useful. Can you amend your question with details? (Model of display, what cable you are using to connect it). Also have you tried changing resolutions on both displays to see if it affects behavior?

Comment: @pion added info about 2nd display. Going to test running at lower res.